# Regarding the value of an expression

Tags: real-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $s>0$, and let $r\in [0,1)$.
Consider the value $I_s(r)=\frac{2}{1-s}((1-r+\pi)^{1-s}-(1-r)^{1-s})$. The last line of of the proof of Lemma 1.2 in [this article on Hardy Spaces](http://homepage.sns.it/fricci/papers/hardy.pdf) says that

$I_s(r)\asymp 1$ if $s<1$

and $I_s(r)\asymp (1-r)^{-(s-1)}$ if $s>1.$
Can anyone tell how?

Comment: What do you mean by $\approx$?

Comment: @ uniquesolution I am sorry for the wrong symbol. I have changed it now. The meaning of the symbol '$\asymp$' can be found here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764897/what-does-this-asymp-symbol-mean-subject-analytic-number-theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the proof of lemma 2.15 [here.](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/mauras/har-ber-cap1-2-3.pdf)

Comment: Actually when $s<1$, then $I_s(r)=2\int_{0}^{\pi}(1-r+\pi)^{-s}$ which is finite as $r$ tends to 1. And when $s>1$, take $(1-r)^{1-s}$ common in $I_s(r)$ and express the remaining term as a finite integral.

Comment: Yes, that makes things much clear.