# What does this symbol for asymptotic growth mean?

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics

In [E.J. Cand`es, D.L. Donoho, New tight frames of curvelets and optimal representations of objects with C2
singularities, Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 56 (2004) 219–266.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.162.1548&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on page 3 I find the following relation (eq. 1.1):
[image]

I tried detexify to identify the latex code for this symbol and work from there, but no success. What does this symbol mean?

Comment: \asymp : see [What does this $\asymp$ symbol mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764897/what-does-this-asymp-symbol-mean-subject-analytic-number-theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically write $f\asymp g$ to mean *$f$ is asymptotic to $g$*, i.e., both $f\ll g$ and $g\ll f$. (This means the same as $f=O(g)$ and $g=O(f)$, or just $f=\Theta(g)$). This is how Graham, Knuth and Patashnik define $\asymp$ in [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics).

In other words, $f\asymp g$ means that there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$\tfrac1C\,g(x) \leqslant |f(x)| \leqslant C\,g(x)$$
for all $x$.

Have a look at [this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf) chapter explaining different asymptotic notations.

Comment: Thank you. I was familiar with $\mathcal{O}$ but not this.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I would avoid using `\mathcal` for big-Oh, it's quite conventional to just use $O({}\cdot{})$.