# What is this math symbol?

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, notation, network

I am learning statistical network analysis and came across this symbol (highlighted in the screenshot below) that I do not know what it means.

[image: The Symbol]

Comment: Detexify gives `$\asymp$` for $\asymp$.

Comment: The symbol is often used in asymptotic analysis and can mean several things. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764897/what-does-this-asymp-symbol-mean-subject-analytic-number-theory)

Comment: Thank you SO much!